# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error in optimization

Tags: r, optimization

This is my first post, I hope I don't make a mistake.

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with nonlinear equality constraints in R using NlcOptim.

I defined my objective function as well as my constraints, but when I run it, it gives me:

Error in if (maxga > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have looked at the details of NlcOptim to figure out what "maxga" is, but unfortunately I am too newbie to figure out the problem.

Here is my code:

```
    beta<-2
    alpha<-3
    theta__<-function(x){((beta+1)/2)*(x[3]+x[4])+(alpha/2)*((x[2]-x[1])/(x[4]-x[3]))}
    profit__A<-function(x) -x[1]*pnorm(theta__(x))
    con=function(x){
       f=NULL
       f=rbind(f,2*(x[4]-x[3])*(1- pnorm(theta__(x)))/(dnorm(theta__(x)*alpha))-x[2])
       f=rbind(f,2*(x[4]-x[3])*(pnorm(theta__(x)))/(dnorm(theta__(x)*alpha))-x[1])
return(list(ceq=f,c=NULL))}
      x0=c(3,2,1,0) 
      solnl(x0,objfun=profit__A,confun=con)
```